# Gulp with watchify/browserify runs once then stops watching

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify, watchify

I have the following gulp task (originally from [this blog](http://tylermcginnis.com/reactjs-tutorial-pt-2-building-react-applications-with-gulp-and-browserify/)):

```js
var path = {
    MAIN_JSX: './myapp/app/jsx/main.js',
    APP_DIR: 'myapp/app',
    APP_JS: 'app.js',
};

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    var watcher = watchify(browserify({
        entries: [path.MAIN_JSX],
        transform: [reactify],
        debug: true,
        cache: {}, packageCache: {}, fullPaths: true
    }));

    return watcher.on('update', function () {
        watcher
            .bundle()
            .on('error', function(err) {
                console.log(err.message)
                this.end();
            })
            .pipe(source(path.APP_JS))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(path.APP_DIR));
        console.log('Updated on ' + (new Date().toString()));
    })
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log(err.message)
            this.end();
        })
        .pipe(source(path.APP_JS))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.APP_DIR));
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

The task runs first time I issue gulp command; and then first time I update `main.js` file. After that it doesn't run at all. What's wrong here?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it per se (although it is a bad idea to duplicate the code from `.bundle()` through `gulp.dest()`). What versions of browserify and watchify? If you eliminate the gulp part does it make any difference in terms of rebundling on subsequent updates of `main.js`?

Answer (score 0):

There was a lot of discussion about this problem [here on Github](https://github.com/substack/watchify/issues/216).

Though it sounds like there may be a number of things going on to cause this issue, I followed the same tutorial on Ubuntu 14.04 and what worked for me was to use Watchify's polling feature:

```
var watcher = watchify(..., {poll: true});
```

From the discussion on Github it sounds like this worked for some people but not others.